# How to serve deep learning model using tensorflow lite

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to serve an image caption model based on flickr8k [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/adityajn105/flickr8k) using TensorFlow lite in the android app.
I am new to Android App development and stuck at the below code where I need to provide input to Feature0 and Feature1 to my model.

Can someone please guide me how to do so?

```
try {
            Model3 model = Model3.newInstance(MainActivity.this);

            // Creates inputs for reference.
            TensorBuffer inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 37}, DataType.FLOAT32);
            inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer);
            TensorBuffer inputFeature1 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 4096}, DataType.FLOAT32);
            inputFeature1.loadBuffer(byteBuffer);

            // Runs model inference and gets result.
            Model3.Outputs outputs = model.process(inputFeature0, inputFeature1);
            TensorBuffer outputFeature0 = outputs.getOutputFeature0AsTensorBuffer();

            // Releases model resources if no longer used.
            model.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Handle the exception
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert you image to bitmap. Then covert your bitmap into a bytebuffer

```
TensorBuffer inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 37}, DataType.FLOAT32);
TensorImage tensorImage = new TensorImage(DataType.FLOAT32);
tensorImage.load(bitmap);
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = tensorImage.getBuffer();
inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer);
```